# Google Tag Manager selecting element inside desired element

Tags: html, google-tag-manager

I am trying to have a tag fire based off an element's ID. The HTML contains a card with other elements inside of it. The outer-most parent div contains the ID that I want to track with GTM. When I run the GTM Preview and click on the element, the trigger doesn't fire and when I click to expand the Click details in GTM it shows that I clicked on an element inside the card, rather than the element with the ID "card-1". I was however able to get the element to fire when I moved the `id="card-1"` to the img inside the card, and make sure I clicked on the img.

I have the trigger configured to fire on "Click ID" that contains "card-1".

How can I fire the trigger for when the user clicks anywhere inside the card?

HTML:

```
  <div class="card-container cursor-pointer" (click)="cardClick()" id="card-1">
    <img class="img-p" src="{{ selected?.image }}">
    <div class="headline title">{{selected?.title}}</div>
    <div class="paragraph body">{{selected?.body}}</div>
    <div class="link body">Learn more</div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="report-modal-container">
        <p>Sample text
        </p>
      </div>
      <img src="assets/pic.png">
      <div class="small"> Other text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your cardClick() to something like...

```
  <div class="card-container cursor-pointer" (click)="cardClick(this)" id="card-1">
```

Then modify cardClick to...

```
function cardClick(e){
 //include the rest of your own code
 
 //push card-click event along with id to dataLayer to consume in GTM
 dataLayer.push({
    'card-id': e.target.id
    'event':'card-click'
 })

}
```

Then in GTM, setup this variable to capture the card id, default value is optional:
[image]

Then setup this trigger:
[image]

Now you should be able to use it in any tag that you want. Example as a GA Event:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

select your element like this:

```
#card-1, #card-1 *
```

[image]